# Convert a obscure? date format in a sql query to a human readable one

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I've got a date format in a bigint field in this format "20130314123743" - YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and i need to do a mysql query on it and get it back to the user in something like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Is there a native mysql function that will take that date format and return it to something human readable?

Comment: Maybe http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring helps? I highly doubt there's a preset conversion function in MySQL for that sort of thing.

Comment: Are you sure that's a date-formatted bigint (ie. 2013-03-14 12:37:43), rather than a Unix-style datetime (ie. number of seconds since Jan 01 1970)?

Comment: @MarkBannister Yeah, that isn't a seconds thing, it's just the bits of a date & time shoved together with no separators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach:

```
select cast(cast(bigintdateval as char(14)) as datetime)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/894c1/1).

Comment: Dude, that is absolutely perfect. I could seriously kiss you right now.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to a datetime you can use MySQL function **FROM_UNIXTIME**

```
FROM_UNIXTIME (unix_timestamp, [format ])

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(20130314123743, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

Exemple;

```
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDay/100000, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS date 
    FROM  person;
```

source
[FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Hope that help

Comment: If you try running this command, you get NULL. Note that, as discussed in the comments on the question, this **isn't** a unix datetime; it's a date-formatted bigint.